# Crontab is not running mysql command

Tags: mysql, cron, cronexpression

I have set up a cronjob using `crontab -e` as follows:

```
12 22 * * * /usr/bin/mysql >> < FILE PATH >
```

This does not run the mysql command. It only creates a blank file.
Whereas mysqldump command is running via cron.
What could the problem be?

Comment: Off topic; belongs on [sf] or possibly [su]

Comment: I'm not so certain of that, Jim. Both cron and MySQL are "software tools commonly used by programmers" as per the FAQ. Database _users_ don't mess about with cron jobs, usually only the developers do that.

Answer (score 2):

Surely `mysql` is the interactive interface into MySQL.

Assuming that you're just running `mysql` and appending the output to your file with `>>`, the first time it tries to read from standard input, it will probably get an end-of-file and exit.

Perhaps you might want to think about providing a command for it to process, something like:

```
12 22 * * * /usr/bin/mysql
                -u me
                -p never_you_mind
                -e "select * from my_table"
                -D my_database
                >>/home/me/output_file
```

(split across multiple lines for readability, but should be on one line).

As an aside, that's not overly secure since your password may be visible from `ps` while the process is running. Since it's only an example, I'm not too worried, but you should consider storing the password in a properly secured `my.cnf` file if you go down this path.

In terms of running a shell script from `cron` which in turn executes MySQL commands, that should work as well. One choice is with a here-doc:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u me -p never_you_mind -D my_database <<EOF
    select * from my_table
    select * from my_other_table where id = 74
EOF
```

Comment: So is it not possible to run mysql command via cron ? Actually, I will run mysql command in shell script which will in turn be run via cron.

Comment: No, it is possible, I've updated the answer to show how (from memory). What's not possible is doing it _interactively_ from `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

```
12 22 * * * /usr/bin/mysql >> < FILE PATH > 2>&1
```

Redirect your error message to the same file so you can debug it.

There is also a good [article](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/debug-cron) about how to debug cron jobs:
[How to debug a broken cron job](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/debug-cron)